# Removing time expressions from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, time

I'm having trouble with  function I'm writing. The goal is to have a string as input:

i.e. `'from 16:00-17:00 we will be bowling and from 18:00-19:00 there is dinner'`

It should return a list with `[16:00-17:00, 18:00-19:00]`

I wanted to use `regex` for this, and use the `re.findall` to search for the time patterns. I can't however get it to work.

Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your code and your attempts?

Comment: Quick tips: 1/. `\d` Matches any decimal digit. Equivalent to [0-9].  2/. `a{3}`
Matches exactly 3 consecutive `a` characters. With this base you should be able to quickly do your regexp. 3/. Here is a [quick testing zone](https://regex101.com/r/rpoKpb/2) I understand you need for a solution but can you please take a [tour] and read more about [ask].

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2})(?is)',s)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern: `\d{2}\:\d{2}\-\d{2}\:\d{2}`

- `\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]), that appears 2 times
- `\:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- `\-` matches the character - literally (case sensitive)

**Code:**

```
import re

strs = ['from 16:00-17:00 we will be bowling and from 18:00-19:00 there is dinner',
    'from 12:00-14:00 we will be bowling and from 15:00-17:00 there is dinner',
    'from 10:00-16:30 we will be bowling and from 18:30-18:45 there is dinner']

pat = '\d{2}\:\d{2}\-\d{2}\:\d{2}'

for s in strs:
    times = re.findall(pat, s)
    print(times)
```

**Output:**

```
['16:00-17:00', '18:00-19:00']
['12:00-14:00', '15:00-17:00']
['10:00-16:30', '18:30-18:45']
```

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/jsjFye/3)